# Liferay forms - access form data

Tags: forms, rest, liferay

In Liferay 7.0, it is easy to define custom forms. Is there a way of accessing the form data which are stored in a liferay through a simple rest-calls?

I.e. having a form called "applications" containing fields (depicted as a JSON for the sake of this example):

```
{ "name" : "adam", "text" : "this is sample text", "date" : "2017-03-08" }
```

Now I would like to list all the forms submitted within certain date range through a rest-call. Is this somehow possible?

Or is the only chance to build some spring-data client or a dedicated portlet over a liferay database?

Comment: The content for submitted forms is stored in the `ddmContent` table and it appears there isn't a remote service for `DDMContent`, only the local one - `DDMContentLocalService`. So I don't think there's a way to get at the submitted form data via Liferay's web services at /api/jsonws. So I think your best bet would be to write your own module that gets the data via `DDMContentLocalService` and exposes it as a web service.